# Problem Updating from CUDA-5.0 to 6.5

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, cuda, nvidia-current-dev

I just tried updating from CUDA-5.0 to CUDA-6.5 and seem to have broken my GUI interface. I tried  to update with the following procedure:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

I then updated my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables so that they contained paths to `/usr/local/cuda-6.5`.

However, when I reboot my machine, the resolution of the logon screen is wrong - everything is slightly too large, and after I logon, all I get is the background screen. I have no access to icons or menus, although my touchpad still works and I can move a pointer around the screen.

When I switch to one of my virtual terminals, I can verify that:

1. `lspci` still shows my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670MX
2. `/usr/bin/cuda-6.5` is installed
3. `nvcc -V` shows 'Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.12'

But, `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` claims there is no such file or directory.
Also, I don't even have the `/proc/driver/nvidia` directory.

I think that I somehow removed my nvidia drivers, even though I still get some graphics for the logon screen.

Does anyone know how I can fix things or what other debugging steps I should try, so that I can use my GUI interface again?

Thanks...

PS

I just tried to install the nvidia-340 driver by:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`

It seems to claim that nvidia-340 is installed

```
 nvidia-340 is already the newest version. 
 nvidia-340 set to manually installed
```

but there's still no `/proc/driver/nvidia` directory... Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with ubuntu gnome 14.04 (Gnome 13.10). I have followed the same steps you mentioned, installing cuda 6.5 and removing 5.5 (that comes with the standard ubuntu repositories). After that `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version/` gave no results.

Moreover rebooting resulted in a failure in loading the login screen (the screen was fixed on the gnome splash screen). I could login with command line, using the command <kbd>ALt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, but I wasn't able to have the GUI working.

After a day of trial and error of recovery attempts (and many Ubuntu reinstalls), I've found that the problem was gdm, so I solved my problem installing lightdm and rebooting with it. This was needed only for the first reboot after cuda installation, then I could revert to gdm.

Hope it helps.